# Mutable array of mutable arrays with modern syntax

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

How can I write the following code:

```
self.box = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                    [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:_imageView1,_imageView2,_imageView3,nil],
                    [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:_imageView4,_imageView5,_imageView6,nil],
                    [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:_imageView7,_imageView8,_imageView9,nil],
                    nil];
```

with the modern syntax?

Comment: Do you really need mutable arrays? It's quite unlikely for UI elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will self answer: for NSMutableArray there is no literal syntax, so you have to write:

```
  self.box = [@[
    [@[ _imageView1, _imageView2, _imageView3 ] mutableCopy],
     [@[ _imageView4, _imageView5, _imageView6 ] mutableCopy],
     [@[ _imageView7, _imageView8, _imageView9 ] mutableCopy]
    ] mutableCopy];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to do it with fewer brackets than your own answer you can use:

```
self.box = @[
             @[_imageView1, _imageView2, _imageView3].mutableCopy,
             @[_imageView4, _imageView5, _imageView6].mutableCopy,
             @[_imageView7, _imageView8, _imageView9].mutableCopy
           ].mutableCopy;
```

Comment: I wouldn't use dot notation here since mutableCopy is a normal method and not a property: - (id)mutableCopy; Although it is shorter it can lead to confusing code like: 'someObject.someReallyExpensiveMethod' and 'NSMutableArray.alloc.init.count'.

Comment: @MaartenFoukhar - I almost wrote in the answer that some might not like this as `mutableCopy` is declared as a method with a property getter-like type, but decided not to - didn't want to upset sensitive Swiftees ;-) Joking aside I think they key word is *like*, and yes it can be abused if taken to extreme but this case doesn't. (I'll admit I often write `.new` as well, but never `.alloc.init`!)